# Windows Phone 8.1 emulator stuck when creating system restore point

Tags: windows-installer, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have problem while install the Window phone emulator 8.1 It stuck in the creating a system restore point. I don't know why? The installer keep running like nothing. after 2 hours and nothing happens, the installer still running anh the status bar do not fill. It because the internet or something on the system?
Do you guys have similiar problem???

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the antivirus software and\or firewall might interfere with Windows phone Emulator installation. Try disabling those and installing again.

Comment: I already turn off the firewal and i don''t have any antivirus so the problem can be the connection? True?